Find all $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x^2)=xf(x)$
I'm pretty sure the only solutions are $f(x)\in \{kx,0\}$ where $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Which I'm stuck at trying to prove because it is not completely a bijective function and the extra $x$ term is annoying to deal with. Any clues on how to proceed?

Right I edited it

Also, do you want to assume $f$ is continuous?  There are some discontinuous solutions.

Just all functions

Then you're missing a lot.  The discontinuous solutions can in general be very wild.

Maybe just the continuous solutions but I'm curious of the discontinuous ones (basically willing to learn)

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's f(x^2)=f(x) (note that, despite the title, the actual functional equation it asks about is the same as yours).

For $x, y > 0$, define $x \sim y$ if and only if $y = x^{2^n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  It can be checked that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.
Pick some $k_C \in \mathbb{R}$ for each equivalence class $C \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}/{\sim}$.  Then $f$ has the form
\begin{align*}
0 &\mapsto 0 \\
x &\mapsto k_C x \\
-x &\mapsto - k_C x
\end{align*}
where $x \in C$.
Most of these solutions are discontinuous.  A simple example is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    2^{2^n - 1} & x = 2^{2^n} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
    -2^{2^n - 1} & x = -2^{2^n} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In fact, @dm63's answer shows that $f$ is continuous if and only if all $k_C$ are equal, namely $f(x) = kx$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

If x is positive there appears to be the following argument: $$ f(x^2)=x f(x) = x.x^{1/2} f(x^{1/2}) = x. x^{1/2} x^{1/4}f(x^{1/4}) = ....$$  which in the limit tends to $x^2 f(1)$ , demonstrating that $f(x)=kx$ as required. This seems to need $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=1$.  Is this valid?

So far, I've got that $f(0) = 0$, and for all $x ≠ 0$:
$$f(-x)^2 = -xf(-x) = f\left(x^2\right) = xf(x)$$
As a result, $f(-x) = -f(x)$, i.e., $f$ is an odd function. See what you can do from here…

just to be sure how is $f(-x)^2=-xf(-x)$?

Given that $f(x^2) = xf(x)$, input $x\mapsto -x$ to obtain that. By the way, $f(-x)^2 = f((-x)^2)$.
